# How to get maximum element in a vector that belongs to a range?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++17, stdvector, std

Although there is an explicit for loop solution for the same, I was looking for a solution to get the max in a vector in a given range.

E.g. let's say a vector has `3,5,7,9,5,1,6,7,4,2` and the given range is `[4,8]` then the max element should be `7`.

I was looking for a one liner/short solution using some inbuilt std library functions for the same.

The array contains all positive numbers.

This is what I have tried :

```
int max = -1;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if (arr[i] > max && arr[i] >= low && arr[i] <= high)
        max = arr[i];
```

I am just looking for a simple standard library vector solution.

Comment: you can use `std::max_element()` with `lambda` where you will check if current value is in the range or not

Comment: I think C++20 ranges would make for a nice solution (sort | equal_range | reverse | take(0)), but in C++17 the one in question might be the best possible.

Comment: what should it return when there is no element within the range? `-1` ?

Comment: The way you wrote it is simple enough. You can reduce it to `for (auto e : vec) if (e > max && e >= low && e <= high) max = e;`

Comment: Note that the algorithm above differs subtly from `max_element`: If there are multiple copies of the maximum value, then `max_element` returns the first one, but the original function returns the last one. (Not significant in this case since the values are integers, but could become significant if they are more complex.)

Comment: @RaymondChen "original function" = OPs code? Note it is `<=` and `>=` for the limits, but max is compared via `>`. It does return the first

Comment: Re: your edit, you have to pass a `my_struct` as the initial value. Your definition doesn't allow default construction, so you'll have to pass some values to it. `my_struct{ -1, -1 }` would work

Comment: I was also expecting you to define `bool operator<(my_struct lhs, my_struct rhs)` et. al., and to have `my_struct low { /* some values */ }; my_struct high { /*other values*/ };`

Answer (score 4):

Not always it pays off to squeeze too much in a single line, or to use algorithms always, especially when the loop is clear and readable. Anyhow, if you like you can use `std::accumulate`. The binary operation is rather close to your original code, I just used the conditional operator instead of an if:

```
auto x = std::accumulate(arr.begin(),arr.end(),-1,[high,low](int accu,int elem){
    return (elem > accu && elem >= low && elem <= high ) ? elem : accu;
});
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rPr3zjv1a)

Comment: will this also work if its a vector of structure objects

Comment: @pujadeo sure, why not. I used `int` parameters for clarity here, but they could be `auto` (since C++14 I believe)

Comment: @pujadeo so long as you have defined comparisons for that class type, and have a sentinel "smallest" value of that type

Comment: I meant in that case I ll be needing iterator to that element, but accumulate returns the int

Comment: @pujadeo `std::accumulate(arr.begin(),arr.end(),my_struct{},[high,low](my_struct accu, my_struct elem){
    return (elem > accu && elem >= low && elem <= high ) ? elem : accu;
});` returns a `my_struct`

Comment: @pujadeo your question is asking for the value, not iterator. With some modifications it could return the index, but then why not simply use the loop you already have? algorithms are nice when they do what you need out of the box. And almost everything can be expressed in terms of standard algorithms, but sometimes clarity suffers rather than making the code more readable

Comment: @pujadeo anyhow in that case the `std::max_element` answers are probably more appropriate

Comment: @Caleth it does not work, says` error: no matching function for call to ‘my_struct::my_struct()`

Comment: Updated my question with the same

Comment: @pujadeo like I said, you need a "smallest" `my_struct` value. I assumed it had a default constructor in that snippet

Comment: so what do I do now for this case?

Comment: @pujadeo when you have a different question you should actually open a different question. This answer targets the original question. Initially you didnt ask the question you wanted to ask, this can happen, writing good questions is underestimated, it is much more difficult than writing answers. But please consider that your edit invalidates all existing answers, because they were basically answering a different question.

Comment: @pujadeo anyhow, the only reason the code in the edit does not work is because you are calling a constructor that does not exist. Once you fix that the code compiles: https://godbolt.org/z/WWeednP6j

Comment: @pujadeo ps: I allowed myself to rollback your edit, because the problem in the edit was unrelated to the initial question

Answer (score 3):

Similar to [@Yksisarvinen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69194798/2610810), but using `std::tuple`'s `<` to shorten it.

This has a precondition that there is at least one element within range in the input.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <algorithm>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> arr {3,5,7,9,5,1,6,7,4,2};
    int lowerLimit = 4;
    int upperLimit = 8;
    
    auto inRange = [lowerLimit, upperLimit](int value)
    {
        return value >= lowerLimit && value <= upperLimit;
    };
    auto compare = [inRange](int lhs, int rhs) {
        return std::tuple(inRange(lhs), lhs) < std::tuple(inRange(rhs), rhs);
    };
    
    assert(!arr.empty());
    assert(std::any_of(arr.begin(), arr.end(), inRange));
    auto it = std::max_element(arr.begin(), arr.end(), compare);
    int max = *it;
}
```

Comment: this one's is giving me a lot of compiler error, can't comment all

Comment: @pujadeo oops, fixed

Answer (score 1):

While others have shown feasible solutions using standard algorithms, I would like to suggest one similar to [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) implementation. Here, you will get more flexibility what to do, when you provide a non-valid range to the algorithm function.

```
#include <iterator> std::iterator_traits

template<typename Iterator>
using EleType = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type;

template< class Iterator>
auto my_max_element(Iterator first, const Iterator last,
    EleType<Iterator> minValue, EleType<Iterator> maxValue)
{
    Iterator largest = first;
    for (; first != last; ++first)
        if (minValue <= *first && *first <= maxValue && *largest < *first)
            largest = first;
    // final range check for the largest element
    return (minValue <= *largest && *largest <= maxValue) ? largest : last;
}
```

**([See a Live Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3KKdj88Er))**

Comment: It should ignore the values 1, 2, 3 and 9, not the indexes in the vector.

Comment: wait no, u didn't get my question, I meant the number inside the vector itself should be filtered on range

Answer (score 1):

This is far from being a one liner (unless you consider helper functions to not be part of the code, then it sure is one line), but if you really want to use standard algorithms, you need a comparison function that will conform to strict weak ordering.

```
bool inRange(int value, int lowerLimit, int upperLimit)
{
    return value >= lowerLimit && value <= upperLimit;
}

std::vector<int> arr {3,5,7,9,5,1,6,7,4,2};
    
int lowerLimit = 4;
int upperLimit = 8;
auto compare = [lowerLimit, upperLimit](int l, int r){
    if(inRange(l, lowerLimit, upperLimit) && inRange(r, lowerLimit, upperLimit)) {
        // both values are in range, so compare them
        return l < r;
    } else if (inRange(r, lowerLimit, upperLimit)) {
        // r is in range, l is not, l should compare smaller
        return true;
    } else if (inRange(l, lowerLimit, upperLimit)) {
        // l is in range, r is not, r should compare smaller
        return false;
    } else {
        // both are out of range, compare them normally to keep strict weak ordering requirements
        return l < r;
    }
};

auto maxIter = std::max_element(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), compare);
std::cout << "Max value is " << *maxIter;
```

Comment: You're working too hard. The comparison function passed to `max_element` does not need to be a weak order.

Comment: @RaymondChen I guess I could eliminate the last `else if` and always `return false;` if the first two conditions are false, but I'm not 100% sure if that would work in all cases.

Comment: @RaymondChen [doesn't it?](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/alg.sorting#3)

Comment: @Caleth Ooh, I didn't see the requirement hiding up there. Sneaky.

Answer (score -1):

Here's one that utilizes the two standard lib functions `std::sort` and `std::find_first_of`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <algorithm>

// Find max element of sample vector within range of val_range.
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> sample = { 3,5,7,9,5,1,6,7,4,2 };
    vector<int> val_range = { 4,8 };

    // Sort in reverse order
    sort(sample.begin(), sample.end(), greater<int>());
    vector<int>::iterator it = find_first_of(sample.begin(), sample.end(), val_range.begin(), val_range.end(), [](int value, int max_val) {return value <= max_val;} );
    cout << (*it) << endl;
}
```

[See Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vTfvoK9G5)

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <algorithm> // for lower_bound, upper_bound and sort
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 
using namespace std;

int main() {

    vector<int> v = {3,5,7,9,5,1,6,7,4,2};
    
    
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    
    auto lower =  lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 8); // position of the element <= 8
    int k = lower - v.begin();
    k = (v[k] == 8) ? k : k - 1; // if-else
    (v[k] >= 4) ? cout << v[k] << endl : cout << "no Such element in given range [4,8]" << endl;    
    

}
```

using the STL library,

- any element which is max in the range[4,8] also max in range [1,8], therefore, the desired element is the lower bound of 8 itself.

Comment: The "range" is supposed to limit values, not indices.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks for bringing my attention to that, I have made a few changes regarding that and would like if you could check it once.

Comment: Please don't recommend using `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` in an answer on Stack Overflow; use the appropriate *standard* header(s) or expect downvotes.

Comment: `{lower,upper}_bound` expect a sorted range (or rather partitioned, but it doesn't matter here).